# How to have a scroll down and up infinite animation in an overflow div in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, overflow, react-hooks, scrolltop

Basically, I have an overflow list of items with fixed height, so it's always be able to scroll.

So the overflow div will scroll down its content, for example in 4 seconds with 0.5 second delay then scroll up its content in 4 seconds with 0.5 second delay. It will be an infinite loop animation.

The only thing that I know is to use scrollTop to make that works on react.

I'm using useAnimation from https://usehooks.com/useAnimation/.

Below is my attempt. Probably my logic is wrong and need some improvements, currently it only scrolls down, scrolls up will break the code

Current attempt on codesandbox :https://codesandbox.io/s/useanimation-ks9nd

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [scrollValue, setScrollValue] = useState(0);
  const scrollListRef = useRef(null);
  const [scrollState, setScrollState] = useState("down");
  const [scrollHeight, setScrollHeight] = useState(0);
  const [offsetHeight, setOffsetHeight] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (scrollListRef.current !== null) {
      setScrollHeight(scrollListRef.current.scrollHeight);
      setOffsetHeight(scrollListRef.current.offsetHeight);
    }
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (scrollValue === 0) {
      setScrollState("down");
    } else if (scrollValue === scrollHeight - offsetHeight) {
      console.log("state up ne");
      setScrollState("up");
    }
  }, [offsetHeight, scrollHeight, scrollValue]);

  let durationTime = 4000; // seconds
  const animationDown = useAnimation("linear", durationTime / 2, 500);
  let animationUp = useAnimation("linear", durationTime / 2, 500);

  useEffect(() => {
    let scrollMax = scrollHeight - offsetHeight;
    if (scrollState === "down") {
      let value = animationDown * scrollMax;
      setScrollValue(value);
    } else if (scrollState === "up") {
      let value = scrollMax - animationUp * scrollMax;
      // setScrollValue(value)
    }
  }, [animationDown, animationUp, offsetHeight, scrollHeight, scrollState]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let ele = document.getElementById("locationsListScroll");
    ele.scrollTop = scrollValue;
  }, [scrollValue]);

  const lists = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  let ulStyle = {
    padding: 0,
    position: "relative",
    marginLeft: "50%",
    marginTop: "3rem",
    transform: "translate(-25%)",
    maxHeight: 200,
    overflow: "auto"
  };
  let liStyle = {
    listStyleType: "none",
    height: 80,
    width: 80,
    display: "flex",
    border: "1px solid black",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  };
  return (
    <div style={{ overflow: "hidden" }}>
      <ul
        ref={scrollListRef}
        id="locationsListScroll"
        className="row locations-list"
        style={ulStyle}
      >
        {lists.map((item, i) => (
          <li style={liStyle} key={i}>
            {item}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
function useAnimationTimer(duration = 1000, delay = 0) {
  const [elapsed, setTime] = useState(0);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      let animationFrame, timerStop, start;

      // Function to be executed on each animation frame
      function onFrame() {
        setTime(Date.now() - start);
        loop();
      }

      // Call onFrame() on next animation frame
      function loop() {
        animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(onFrame);
      }

      function onStart() {
        // Set a timeout to stop things when duration time elapses
        timerStop = setTimeout(() => {
          cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrame);
          setTime(Date.now() - start);
        }, duration);

        // Start the loop
        start = Date.now();
        loop();
      }

      // Start after specified delay (defaults to 0)
      const timerDelay = setTimeout(onStart, delay);

      // Clean things up
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(timerStop);
        clearTimeout(timerDelay);
        cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrame);
      };
    },
    [duration, delay] // Only re-run effect if duration or delay changes
  );

  return elapsed;
}

function useAnimation(easingName = "linear", duration = 500, delay = 0) {
  // The useAnimationTimer hook calls useState every animation frame ...
  // ... giving us elapsed time and causing a rerender as frequently ...
  // ... as possible for a smooth animation.
  const elapsed = useAnimationTimer(duration, delay);
  // Amount of specified duration elapsed on a scale from 0 - 1
  const n = Math.min(1, elapsed / duration);
  // Return altered value based on our specified easing function
  return easing[easingName](n);
}

// Some easing functions copied from:
// https://github.com/streamich/ts-easing/blob/master/src/index.ts
// Hardcode here or pull in a dependency
const easing = {
  linear: n => n,
  elastic: n =>
    n * (33 * n * n * n * n - 106 * n * n * n + 126 * n * n - 67 * n + 15),
  inExpo: n => Math.pow(2, 10 * (n - 1))
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core problem of your logic is that the `animationUp` hook will immediately starts along with the `animationDown`.

You said, that **It will be an infinite loop animation**, but as we all know *hooks must be initialized on the root level of the component*. So we can't use your approach with two separate instance of the animation hooks. We need to somehow reset the animation hook every time when we reach the **finish** of the current animation.

Instead we can use the existing behavior of the `useAnimationTimer` dependency of re-initialization - **Only re-run effect if duration or delay changes**. It looks like a hack and this is something that can definitely must be improved. And one more significant modification - add the `animationState` to the original animation timer, so it can give us the exact checkpoints of animation.

**Working example**: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infinite-scroll-animation-ud0xq)

Comment: Great, thank you for your solution. It seems working now, I will look into your code soon, anyways I will accept your answer.